# "Missing parameters" error for CiviMail unsubscribes

Tags: civimail, error

Using Drupal 7.69 and CiviCRM 5.26.1.

Some (not all) of our users are getting the following error page when they try and unsubscribe via URL from our mailings.

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
> moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> with more details about what action you were performing when this
> occurred. Missing Parameters

The link they've been taken to is https://****.com/civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe?reset=1&jid=&qid=&h=

The Drupal error log gives quite a length error message which I've pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/uazpw4Pz).

This has happened with a few different users. With the error message above, it's important to note that:

1. One user said it didn't work, while another user was able to successfully unsubscribe using the URL
2. The user who said it didn't work, was in our database with email1@gmail but emailed us reporting the error using email2@gmail, so they might have set up an auto redirect from email1@gmail to email2@gmail, so they might have clicked on the link from email2@gmail (not in our database). This is an assumption and not confirmed; if there's a possibility this could be triggering it I will ask the user if they are having their emails redirected.

Other people have had this error and said they've fixed it by upgrading to Civi 5.24 but we're at 5.26.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just spotted that I can replicate the issue but going to 'View in Browser' and then clicking on the unsub link. will be checking to see if i can replicate on latest Civi + Mosaico